# Html email cell padding assistance

Tags: html, html-table, html-email, campaign-monitor

Need assistance adding padding to the main body text of this emailer so the text does not look quite so tight to the border.

It's probably a simple solution but I can't work out which table to add the cell padding property to.

live version -> http://garyrevell.co.uk/mercy2013/2013-temp/alt-april-mailer/index-purple-final.html

Pastebin of the code -> http://pastebin.com/PAbYgqXN

Help would be much appricated.

Answer (score 0):

Always add padding the the table cell that the content is in. eg:

```
<td style="padding:30px;">
<singleline>your content</singleline>
</td>
```

It looks like your content however is living outside of tables in divs instead. You should lose the divs and put everything into td sections. Also, don't have a table next to text inside a parent td, instead have a table cell for each (use table rows if stacking them).